# Add radio group to Table LAyout, android?

Tags: android, tablelayout

[image]

This is the layout I want to create but dynamically through java code.
Here parent layout is LinearLayout.

The tableLayout created through java code consists of 5 radio buttons which are created dynamically.

I need to place these radio button in radio group.
How to do that.

So far i tried this which is working fine. But am not able to add all the 5 radio buttons in 1 radio group.

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainl); //parent layout

    t1 = new TableLayout(this);

    rb1 = new RadioButton(this);
    rb2 = new RadioButton(this);
    rb3 = new RadioButton(this);

    t1.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
    TableRow row1 = new TableRow(this);

    row.addView(rb1);
    row.addView(rb2);
    row1.addView(rb3);

    t1.addView(row);
    t1.addView(row1);
    l.addView(t1);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't find you'r declaration of a RadioGroup.

You need something like this:

```
...

RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this);
rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);

rg.addView(rb1);
rg.addView(rb2);
rg.addView(rb3);

row.addView(rg);

...
```

Comment: this is not what i want, In 1st row 2 radio buttons, in 2nd row 2 radio buttons, in 3rd row 1 radio button. Add all these radio buttons to radio group

Answer (score 0):

`RadioGroup` inherits from `LinearLayout`. You'll have to create your own implementation of RadioGroup that inherits from `TableLayout`.

If you examine the [source code](https://code.google.com/p/android-source-browsing/source/browse/core/java/android/widget/RadioGroup.java?repo=platform--frameworks--base&name=android-4.2.1_r1&r=579e14016c4a972e70cd2bd0c6d89bbd7e9e941c&spec=svn.platform--frameworks--base.b361b3043bb351ab175ae1ff3dae4de9fe31d42b) of `RadioGroup`, you'll see it just keep track of its child views which are `RadioButton`'s and makes sure only one of them is checked. Apart from that it provides a listener if checked `RadioButton` changes.

You can try modifying the source to make it extend from `TableLayout` etc.